# Custom jQuery plugin not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I've written the following as a plugin so I can use it in multiple areas on my site. It's an autocomplete feature that displays a drop down list of all the names on the database as you type the first few letters into a text input.

Unfortunately, although it works beautifully in Chrome, Firefox and IE9+, it doesn't seem to work in IE8 or below. I'm using the Chrome IE emulator to test it and when I start typing into the box, absolutely nothing happens.

I've tried adding in an `alert` immediately after the `$.fn.customAutocomplete = function() {` line. In Firefox this causes the `alert` to show as soon as the page loads. In IE8 it does nothing - this suggests to me that IE8 is not including the plugin on page load, but I have no idea why! Any help would be appreciated - full code is below:

EDIT: For the record, I'm using jQuery 1.8.3 if that makes any difference.

```
(function($){
$.fn.customAutocomplete = function() {

    return this.each(function(){
      var obj = $(this);


      obj.on('input', function(){

       var autoName = obj.val();
       var autoLength = autoName.length;
       var url = 'http://xenonacademy.org.uk/autoComplete.php';
       //console.log(autoLength);
         //$('.autoNameEntry').remove();
         $('.autoNameDiv').remove();
         if (autoLength != 0){
         $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: "POST",
           data: {autoName : autoName},
           success: function(data){
           obj.parent().append(data);

           }
        });
        }
        else {
        //$('.autoNameEntry').remove();
         $('.autoNameDiv').remove();
        }
      })
      $(document).on('click', '.autoNameEntry', function(){
       event.stopPropagation();
       var getName = $(this).find('.autoName').html();
       var getUserID = $(this).find('.userID').val();
       obj.parent().find('.hiddenUserID').val(getUserID);
       obj.parent().find('.hiddenUserID').trigger('change');
       obj.val(getName);
       //obj.trigger('change');
       $('.autoNameDiv').remove();
      });
    });

  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What is the "Chrome IE emulator"?

Comment: Can you upload a demo to http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io?

Comment: It's a plugin for Chrome which allows you to view pages as if they were in Internet Explorer. I have IE10 on my machine and have no way of installing earlier versions so I have to use this for testing.

Comment: I can but not sure how it will work as I won't be able to connect it to the DB (I've never used jsfiddle before so not sure quite how it works)

Comment: [How can I change IE10's default browser mode to IE8?](http://techathlon.com/internet-explorer-10-run-compatibility-mode/)

Comment: *"In IE8 it does nothing - this suggests to me that IE8 is not including the plugin on page load"* that's not at all what it suggests. That is a possibility, but there are a dozen or more other reasons it could be *"not working"*. you need to debug it further to find the cause.

Comment: @Chris: Can you provide a link to this chrome plugin?  Also, Microsoft provides VMs for IE testing.  They have one with WinXP and IE8.  http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools

Comment: The link to the Chrome plugin is: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en

Comment: After Blazemonger's suggestion, I've tried the IE8 emulator built into IE10 and the same thing happens

Comment: Why are you calling `$(document).on('click', '.autoNameEntry', function(){` *inside* the `this.each(`?

Comment: Rocket Hazmat - this is the first time I've written something as a plugin so haven't quite got it right yet - what should I be doing instead?

Comment: Move that event outside of the `$.fn.customAutocomplete = function() {` function.  That only needs to be bound once.

Comment: I've now tested with an `alert` immediately after the `$function($){` line and it works in IE8, so it seems as though the problem lies somewhere within the `customAutocomplete` function

Comment: Do you see any errors in IE8?  Or does it just not do anything?  What do you see in the console (if you open it and the refresh the page)?

Comment: Not seeing any error messages, either in the main browser window or in the console

Comment: I've moved the event outside of the function but still not working

Comment: @Chris: I never said that was a solution.  It was just something that I figured I should mention.

Comment: Ah apologies, wishful thinking on my part! Is there an article somewhere which covers this kind of thing? What are some of the common reasons for IE8 not playing with jQuery?

Comment: I think I figured something out!  It looks like the `oninput` event only works in IE9+.  (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oninput and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg592978.aspx) Try `obj.on('change', function(){`

Comment: That's done it! THanks! I've used on('keyup') instead as I want it to be live as people are typing  but that seems to be working fine. Thanks!!